# rsync delete-excluded without implied delete

Tags: backup, rsync

I'd like to use `rsync` to back up my home directory to another drive, but I have some directories I want to exclude. I have a past backup that contains those directories but I want them gone from the backup. How can I use rsync to delete those directories on the receiving drive without deleting files that aren't in the exclude list but are missing from the source dir? In other words, how can I get the effect of `--delete-excluded` without the implied `--delete`?

The following filter seems like it should work but doesn't:

```
# dirs I want to delete on the receiving side
H .cache
H cache

# don't delete missing files from here
+ /
```